# Android not scaling viewport

Tags: android, html, viewport, meta

This viewport is scaling down perfectly for iphones but it does nothing right but preventing the user to zoom on the site for android phones.

The site has 1080px width, how can I scale it down to 320px correctly?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

i would say use css to over come this i had the same problem and i sorted it using css it does mean doing a bit more css coding but i think it would be your easier option in my work with IOS and android i find it easyer to worek with IOS as they not that far of desktop browser standards un like android

Comment: well, cant really edit the css because the project has atleast 30K rows css.. :/

Comment: is this a mobile website or a responsive website

Comment: it's a mobile website

Answer (score 0):

Try setting scalable to NO rather than 0;

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

this usually works for me.

Steve

Comment: the site should be downscaled at start, this question is about scaling down the website not scalable :) @SteveDavis